# Is it possible to add a custom style to a Word document using a Java Script add-in?

Tags: ms-word, styles, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm a relatively novice JS developer and I'm developing a Word add-in using Visual Studio 2019. I'm using the following code to insert XML into the active document with the intention of adding a custom style to the document.

```
function addCustomStyle() {
        let myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var myXML;
        myOOXMLRequest.open("GET", "./CustomStyle.xml", false);
        myOOXMLRequest.send();

        if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
            myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
        }

        Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
            myXML,
                        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Ooxml},
            function (asyncResult) {
                let error = asyncResult.error;
                if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("XML injection success");
                }
                    });
    }
```

I get "Data Write Error: Cannot write to the current selection.: The format of the specified data object is invalid." with the following data in my CustomStyle.xml file:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
                                <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/styles.xml" 
pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
  <pkg:xmlData>
    <w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >
      <w:style w:type="character" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="tester">
        <w:name w:val="tester"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="DefaultParagraphFont"/>
        <w:uiPriority w:val="1"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="00E82EF6"/>
      </w:style>
    </w:styles>
  </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
             </pkg:package>
```

Any and all ideas and advice gratefully accepted.

Cheers.

Tim

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Thanks for correcting my tagging. Much appreciated.